# Was anybody able to successfully configure messaging for web for salesforce?

Tags: chat, messaging-for-web

We need chat bot integration into the customer website.

I have explored several options for POC.

For now we don't have access to the customer website, so we tried to add Salesforce Chat link to Salesforce Public site and it seems to be working.

However, Salesforce chat feature is deprecated and Salesforce documentation suggests  messaging for web should be used. We tried to configure it for both Salesforce Public Site and Salesforce Experience Cloud portal but neither option works.

Whatever we do we still see `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'` error

[image]

Is that expected? Is the Salesforce Chat more robust product option to choose?

Comment: Yes, using force.com site in a PoC. Have you added the site url to CORS?